# How to get Floating Action Button to work in Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android

I have tried almost every code and suggestion out there concerning putting a Floating Action Button in a Xamarin layout, but I am always getting an inflation error. This is the XML file

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark" />
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
<!-- The Main Content View -->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <TextView
            android:text="10 mins"
            android:textSize="100dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/timerView" />
        <TextView
            android:text="left of Period 4"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/timerView"
            android:id="@+id/timerViewBottom" />
        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/myFAB"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_plus_sign"
        app:elevation="4dp"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
<!-- The Left Navigation Drawer -->
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="#818181"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:background="#D3D3D3" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
 </LinearLayout>
```

I am using a AppCompat Theme. What is wrong? My android api is 23

Answer (score 0):

Do you attached your floatingActionButton in your listview?

In in your activity or fragment, whatever, you have to attach the floating button in your listview, something like this:

```
var myListView = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.left_drawer);
var myFloatingButton = FindViewById<FloatingActionButton>(Resource.Id.myFAB);

myFloatingButton.AttachToListView(myListView);
```